# Regex to find trailing numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that looks like:

```
www.blah.com/asdf/asdf/asdfasedf/123
```

The string may have a slash followed by numbers, like /123 in the above example.

I want to extract the 123 from the string if it is present.

What would my regex be?

Comment: Where do these URLs come from? Are they entered manually somewhere or are they gathered from an HTTP request? Could there be a trailing slash? What if the number is the middle i.e. `example.com/123/asdf`? You'll need some more specifications to get the best possible answer... regex may not even be necessary here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terminate your regular expression with $ to signify the end of the line.

```
\/\d+$
```

To actually extract the number, use:

```
int number;
var match = Regex.Match(inputString,@"\/(\d+)$");
if(match.Success)
    number = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].ToString());
```

Comment: You also need to make sure the string is not empty not to get the parsing error.

Comment: `Regex.Match` will not throw an exception, and I'm checking for `null` after it. Come to think of it, it might be more correct to test `match.Success` instead. Edited my answer.

Comment: Yea, the match should never be null, even if there is no match the match will be set so match success will be false, when you were using null, the code would still execute even if there would be no groups in the match.

Answer (score 4):

You simply match a group of digits (\d+) and require the string to end after that

```
(\d+)$
```

Answer (score 3):

This will match a slash followed by numbers at the end of a string and capture the numbers:

```
\/(\d*)$
```

Comment: thanks, that is what I came up with also, but the slash seems to be part of the match?

Comment: If you're saying that 'MAY be preceeded with a slash', then the slash shouldn't be a part of the regex!

Comment: In the example I gave, the slash is outside of the capturing parens, and so would not be part of the capture group. You can omit the leading slash if you don't care whether it's there or not. Your example had it preceded with a slash but if the slash is optional, just leave it out.